# How to change my code for layout like a attached pictures in css

Tags: html, css

I wanna make layout like picture of bottom of this post.
But my code doesn't working. 
each column occupies 47% of the width of the overall left section
there is a horizontal spacing of 2% between columns and neighboring content.
I want to make this layout without css new column property.
It has to have 20pt of vertical space between reviews.
How to change or add my code from above.

```css
div#wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*skipped border style*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
  width: 550px;
  height: inherit;
}

div.reviews {
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

div.review {
  width: 47%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 20pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

div.review img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div.review p:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.reviews p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #E8DC9B;
  /*skipped border style*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="rate" class="center">
      <img src="rottenbig.png" alt="Rotten" /> 33%
    </div>
    <div class="reviews">
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Peter Debruge <br /> Variety
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Jeannette Catsoulis <br /> New York Times
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
          <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Todd Gilchrist <br /> IGN Movies
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Joshua Tyler <br /> CinemaBlend.com
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>It stinks!</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Jay Sherman (unemployed)
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Loved it! I'm into turtles and ninjas.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Leo Rafael <br /> HY PetShop Ltd.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Ed Gonzalez <br /> Slant Magazine
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
          <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Mark Palermo <br /> Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Steve Rhodes <br /> Internet Reviews
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Don't really like it!</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Scott Lee <br /> SELab
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="poster" src="overview.png" alt="general overview" />
  </div>


  <dl>
    <dt>STARRING</dt>
    <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

    <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
    <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

    <dt>RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG</dd>

    <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
    <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

    <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
    <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

    <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

    <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
    <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

    <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
    <dd>90 mins</dd>

    <dt>GENRE</dt>
    <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

    <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
    <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

    <dt>LINKS</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>


  <p>(1-10) of 88</p>
</div>
```

[**Result that I wanna make**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qne69.png)

[**Current result of mine**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLeYP.png)

Comment: can you provide working code..?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
.review:nth-child(2n+1) {
 clear: both;
 }
```

```css
div#wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*skipped border style*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
  width: 550px;
  height: inherit;
}

div.reviews {
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

div.review {
  width: 47%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 20pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

div.review img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div.review p:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.reviews p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #E8DC9B;
  /*skipped border style*/
}
.review:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="rate" class="center">
      <img src="rottenbig.png" alt="Rotten" /> 33%
    </div>
    <div class="reviews">
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Peter Debruge <br /> Variety
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Jeannette Catsoulis <br /> New York Times
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
          <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Todd Gilchrist <br /> IGN Movies
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Joshua Tyler <br /> CinemaBlend.com
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>It stinks!</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Jay Sherman (unemployed)
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Loved it! I'm into turtles and ninjas.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Leo Rafael <br /> HY PetShop Ltd.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Ed Gonzalez <br /> Slant Magazine
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
          <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Mark Palermo <br /> Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Steve Rhodes <br /> Internet Reviews
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>
          <img src="rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
          <q>Don't really like it!</q>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="critic.gif" alt="Critic" /> Scott Lee <br /> SELab
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="poster" src="overview.png" alt="general overview" />
  </div>


  <dl>
    <dt>STARRING</dt>
    <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

    <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
    <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

    <dt>RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG</dd>

    <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
    <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

    <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
    <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

    <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

    <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
    <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

    <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
    <dd>90 mins</dd>

    <dt>GENRE</dt>
    <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

    <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
    <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

    <dt>LINKS</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>


  <p>(1-10) of 88</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I just finished trying your feedback, but review boxes of same row have same vertical start point. I want to adjust these start points to different as amount of each above review text.